# Unable to resize the LVM root

Tags: centos, lvm

I want to increase the size of /dev/mapper/centos_rayman7-root to 7XG (centos 7 in virtualbox), but no matter how i try, the /dev/mapper/centos_rayman7-root keeps showing 36G only

[image]

[image]

anyone know what i'm missing?

[image: output for xfs_grow]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After extending disk, you have to extend your FileSystem.
If `mount` shows the disk as `ext3/4`, then you need to run:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos_rayman7-root
```

If it's `XFS` then this should do the trick:

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/centos_rayman7-root
```

Comment: after i ran xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/centos_rayman7-root, it is the same.

Comment: do you still have output of xfs_growfs ?

Comment: see the new picture, run just after i used gparted

Comment: Even better, if you use cli to extend the LV you can do it with the -r flag. 'lvextend -L 7G -r /Dev/mapper/yadda-root'

Comment: i have new error for my virtualbox. The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards.

Answer (score -4):

I only can suggest you to check that in VirtualBox in the `Media` section you extended all the parent and child disks, not only the child or parent one. See the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Second advice is to go to VM's settings > Storage > turn on `Use Host I/O Cache` for every controller.

Comment: Can you show that the fact that the system is running inside VirtualBox has anything to do with the issue presented in the question?

Comment: I bumped into the same issue with a same `rc=VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error, so I posted my working solution here. Besides OP mentioned `centos 7 in virtualbox` in question body, so yeah, I think it is definitely relates to the question. FYI. My answer originated from [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=512054#p512054).

Comment: There can be several causes of a single error message.  I'm noting that the user in the question does not mention resizing VirtualBox snapshots, nor does it mention the error message that you quote.  They have accepted another answer which we must assume means it resolved their issue.  If you want to expand on the issue that they mention _in the comments_ (i.e. not part of the actual question), then you may post a separate question with a self-answer about this.

Comment: hkguile mentioned `ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards` error in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470477/unable-to-resize-the-lvm-root/757284?noredirect=1#comment860595_470483). Also I see that he accepted answer as solution **before** he got this error.